# Is there a good practice to replace SELECT COUNT(*) by table with a row [Counter] for making a real time dashboard

Tags: sql, design-patterns, database-design, count, relational-database

I have a project where we track the performances of all users and display them in a dashboard. The dashboard refresh every 30 seconds.

I track the users actions in a table named Logs with the rows:

`[IdUser] [IDActionType] [DateTimeAction]`

Now for some clients the table now have 10 millions rows. It's good for keeping a log but not for a dashboard where you do a `SELECT COUNT BETWEEN XDate AND YDate` every 30 seconds. (There's multiple queries and multiples graphs, it's just simplified for the example.)

Is there lectures, texts, websites talking about optimizing a database / good practices around doing tables for a dashboard.

I'm thinking about doing one table by graph and every table would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE GRAPH_USERS_ACTIONS ( [Day], [Action], [Counter] )
```

Where I would just increment the counter. They can do 500 actions per day so by doing that I can divide the rows after one year by 500 and I can delete rows older than one year without deleting the logs.

Is this good practice? I hate that because it is repeating the data we could get by simply doing

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logs where DateTime Between 00:00:00 AND 23:59:59
```

But that select is so long to execute on the old clients servers.

And do you know any detailed articles about this topic?

Comment: At some point, data gets so large that you need to introduce redundant summaries for performance.  It sounds like you have long ago hit that point and summary tables would help.

Comment: "Summary table". Thank you I'll try to google that. English is not my native language and half of my question is on finding articles about this exact subject and I wasn't finding anything by googling "Select COUNT ... ".

Comment: You may want to search for data marts and solutions using OLAP.